# Core data not inserted value in entity in iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-data, ios9, xcode7

I am using coredata in a application. It is perfectly working in iOS 8.4.1. Last night I update my iPod to iOS 9 and I watch that value are not inserted in coredata.

I deleted the class which are generated by coredata in iOS 8.4.1 and generate new class in iOS 9 and I watch that 2 new class is generated for each entity. Suppose I have an entity AllCategory which has entity id,name,imageUrl. My working code till iOS 8.4.1 is

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AllCategories" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSError *error;
NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (count==0)
{
    for (CategoryList *temp in catList)
    {
        AllCategories *book = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AllCategories" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        //[book setBid:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[temp.cat_id intValue]]];
        [book setCatid:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[temp.cat_id intValue]]];
        [book setCatName:temp.cat_Name];
        [book setImage:temp.cat_Image];
        //[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
        NSLog(@"temp.cat_Name=%@---%@",temp.cat_Name,book.catName);
    }
}
```

This code is also working in xCode 7 and iOS 8.4.1

Answer (score 0):

You commented out the call to `save`. That is is why your data is not persisted.

Comment: Now, I recheck it and data are inserted in iPhone simulator but not in iPod touch(iOS 9.01)